# node.js headless browser to access javascript global variables only

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, headless-browser

I have a very simple requirement - access a list of websites and retrieve the values for specific global variables (**window.{variablename}**) . I don't care about rendering the page or images. Something really fast that can just fetch the fetch, probably construct the DOM so I get access the global variables in javascript and retrieve value for **window.{var_name}**

I am able to do with **chrome** headless on selenium on Ubuntu Server. But the problem is that it takes between **1.5 to 3 seconds** (slow) to do this simple task. Since I have to repeat this task quite frequently for a whole bunch of sites, the 3 second time it takes for one site is very slow.

I started looking into **PhantomJs**, **Casper** etc but it seems they're no longer maintained.

Is there a good option to do something as basic as the requirement I mentioned above?

Comment: Is the global variable mutable?  If immutable, could you use a text parser?

Comment: The list of sites is pretty long and I have not looked closely to see if text-parser would work. It'll take some time to go through a lot of them to see if text-parser will work on them.
The easier method would be to have a fast headless browser pull the page, construct DOM so I can do a command like "return window.{var-name}" to get the values.

Comment: Maybe try https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer. Reuse the the browser instance for all tasks.

Comment: Have you tried `--no-single-run`?

Comment: Thanks @madflow. I am reusing the browser instance, it still took more than 1.5 seconds. I'll checkout puppeteer as well.

Comment: Thanks @Mike. I did not try that yet. I'll try it out. I'm also looking into the parsing thing as text for the javascript variable or and also by fetching the page and running it thru cheerio.

The first site I tried has global variable as immutable, but I need to figure out how to clean up the string as it has a lot of "&quot;" and possibly other things in it.

Comment: @Mike, Thank you for suggesting text parsing. I'm able to do that and it has resulted in over 90% savings on CPU time and considerable savings on network time as I don't need to download images.

Comment: That's nice to hear.  Just make sure they're primitives and directly assigned. I was secretly hoping you'd solve the headless issue.  I recall the same issue when switching from PhantomJS to Chrome (accuracy improvement and fairly large speed decrease).  At times (especially for functionality testing), I wish Phantom was maintained despite accuracy issues.

Comment: @Mike, yeah, me too. I wanted to use a generic solution like faster performance in headless without loading images and parsing and rendering the entire page. But I kept running into issues. The custom parser was not my first instinct but seeing the performance gain I'm getting, it is worth it and I don't think it can be beat easily. So I'll stop looking at alternatives at this time.

Comment: @Mike, I still have one issue in this method. I've had to use str.replace() for & encodings like ( &amp; and &quot; ) and will need to add more as I come across other encodings in my script texts. Would you know of any library/module that I can use for parsing (removing all & encodings) by providing a string like ---- <script> window.test = "{stringified JSON content with & encodings peppered everywhere - like between key/value pairs and urls. possibly also within values. }"; </script>.

Comment: Not sure, you may need to post a new question.  Could you just remove them? `str.replace(/&[^&\s]+?\;/g, "");`

Comment: Thanks @Mike. Appreciate you providing the regex, but I need to replace them with their values. Removing them completely will result in loss of information. I'll see if I can create a module for this and If I still need help, I'll post it as a separate question.

Comment: @Curious101 can you create a textarea element?  If so `textarea.innerHTML=<parsedValue>;` then when you call `textarea.value` it'll have the decoded html string.  But you probably want to load the `he` library (stands for HTML entities).  It has a `decode()` method that will do it all for you.

Comment: Thanks @Mike. I'm running this on node, so the document.textarea() is not available, that's why I was considering Cheerio but stopped pursuing it due to some issues I encountered (forget what it was at the moment). I also looked into HTMLparser2 and DomHandler, but ran into some issues there as well. (I found the documentation lacking). I have not looked at HE yet, I'll give it a shot and report back.